# Fill in missing date values with values for preceding dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date, lubridate

I have stock price data for 100 companies. The time series is for daily data from 1/1/2010 to 15/3/2023.

Data is missing for some days because of weekends and public holidays. For example, for company A, the data looks like this.

```
data_a <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-11-01")),
  Price = c(91, 92, 93, 91, 90, 91, 93),
  Company = rep("A", 7)
)
```

I want to smooth the data so that there are no gaps in the dates. A missing date should be filled in with the value for the previous available date.

The resulting data-frame should be:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-06", "2010-01-07", "2010-01-08", "2010-01-09", "2010-01-10", "2010-01-11")),
  Price = c(91, 91, 91, 92, 93, 91, 90, 90, 91, 93, 93),
  Company = rep("A", 11)
)
```

I have not worked with something like this in the past, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` in your `data_a` dataframe has a `ymd` format while your desired output `Date` is in `ydm`. So first transform your `Date` into the same format as your output, then `complete` the record with the range of your desired date, and `fill` missing values with the previous value.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data_a %>% 
  mutate(Date = ydm(Date)) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq(ydm("2010-01-01"), ydm("2010-11-01"), 1)) %>% 
  fill(Price, Company, .direction = "up")

         Date Price Company
1  2010-01-01    91       A
2  2010-01-02    91       A
3  2010-01-03    91       A
4  2010-01-04    92       A
5  2010-01-05    93       A
6  2010-01-06    91       A
7  2010-01-07    90       A
8  2010-01-08    90       A
9  2010-01-09    91       A
10 2010-01-10    93       A
11 2010-01-11    93       A
```

Answer (score 2):

`merge` with a `seq.Date` and `zoo::na.locf`.

```
merge(data_a, data.frame(Date=do.call(seq.Date, c(as.list(range(data_a$Date)), 'month'))), all=TRUE) |>
  transform(Price=zoo::na.locf(Price), Company=Company[!is.na(Company)][1])
#         Date Price Company
# 1 2010-03-01    91       A
# 2 2010-04-01    92       A
# 3 2010-05-01    93       A
# 4 2010-06-01    91       A
# 5 2010-07-01    91       A
# 6 2010-08-01    90       A
# 7 2010-09-01    91       A
# 8 2010-10-01    91       A
# 9 2010-11-01    93       A
```

---

*Data:*

```
data_a <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 
14822, 14853, 14914), class = "Date"), Price = c(91, 92, 93, 
91, 90, 91, 93), Company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the data frame shown in the Note at the end which is the same as the question except we have added a second Company B.

Convert the input data frame to a wide form zoo object using yearmon dates and convert that to a ts object -- that will fill in the missing dates with NA's.  Then convert back to zoo, replace the NA's using `na.locf` (last occurrence carried forward) and finally back to a long form data frame.

We have converted the dates to yearmon class since they are really representing year and month and not full dates but if Date class is wanted anyways then just convert them using `as.Date` afterwards.

If it were known that every output date appears in at least one company then we could omit the `as.ts() |> as.zoo()` since `read.zoo` would already have inserted the needed NA's in converting to wide form.

```
library(zoo)

data2 |>
  read.zoo(split = "Company", FUN = as.yearmon, drop = FALSE) |>
  as.ts() |>
  as.zoo() |>
  na.locf() |>
  fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE, names = names(data2)[c(1, 3, 2)])
```

giving:

```
       Date Company Price
1  Mar 2010       A    91
2  Apr 2010       A    92
3  May 2010       A    93
4  Jun 2010       A    91
5  Jul 2010       A    91
6  Aug 2010       A    90
7  Sep 2010       A    91
8  Oct 2010       A    91
9  Nov 2010       A    93
10 Mar 2010       B    91
11 Apr 2010       B    92
12 May 2010       B    93
13 Jun 2010       B    91
14 Jul 2010       B    91
15 Aug 2010       B    90
16 Sep 2010       B    91
17 Oct 2010       B    91
18 Nov 2010       B    93
```

### Note

```
data2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 
14822, 14853, 14914, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14822, 14853, 
14914), class = "Date"), Price = c(91, 92, 93, 91, 90, 91, 93, 
91, 92, 93, 91, 90, 91, 93), Company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `time_complete()` from my package timeplyr which fills in missing gaps in time and by default uses the time range of your data.

```
data_a <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-11-01")),
  Price = c(91, 92, 93, 91, 90, 91, 93),
  Company = rep("A", 7)
)
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
data_a %>%
  time_complete(time = across(Date, ydm), by = "day") %>%
  fill(Price, Company, .direction = "up")
        Date Price Company
1 2010-01-03    91       A
2 2010-01-04    92       A
3 2010-01-05    93       A
4 2010-01-06    91       A
5 2010-01-07    90       A
6 2010-01-08    90       A
7 2010-01-09    91       A
8 2010-01-10    93       A
9 2010-01-11    93       A
```